# Facebook page iframe does not work

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

the problem is - when I try to use Facebook page plugin - it simply does not show up on my page. Page is hosted, and online, It is using wordpress and bootstrap.
When I try to use iframe it simply does not show nothing.
I use this iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdrugelioefektaslt%2F%3Ffref%3Dts&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId=1081685078553875" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I tries to use simple intergatio generated from facebook development page - but got same result. Code I used right after body opening:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=1081685078553875";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/drugelioefektaslt/?fref=ts" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/drugelioefektaslt/?fref=ts" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/drugelioefektaslt/?fref=ts">Drugelio Efektas</a></blockquote></div>
```

This is facebook development generated code - but it does show only hyperlink to page. Strange thing is, that url in iframe src works normally. Maybe someone can assist with this problem?

Comment: Please check network and console tabs in browser developer tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript generated from Facebook works. Make sure you don't block Facebook with plugin like disconnect.me, ghostery or privacy ublock lists.
You can also provide links to site where it doesn't work so I could check if there are no problems with headers that could maybe block FB scripts. Please check network and console tabs in dev tools.

Comment: Both iframe and JS works just fine. If you block social widgets in your browser I recommend using different browser for working with social plugins.

Comment: Any idea why is that?

Comment: It works for me in Firefox. Have you checked console and network tab in developer tools? If you have extension that is blocking Facebook addresses  there will be information there.

Comment: The problem is, that I use firefox with no plugins, and my friend have same problem.

Comment: What version do you use? No sign of problem in developer tools?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122000/discussion-between-loji-and-justinast).